# Possible pest identification on Weeping Blue Atlas cedar

Tags: identification, pests, insects, cedar

Location is Portland, Oregon, USA.

We have a blue atlas cedar that's at least 20 years old.  It was recently pruned (by an arborist) and now the needles are turning brown.

[image]

[image]

To check for insect pests we shook the branches over a sheet of white paper, and collected a few of the bug below.  The body is between 1mm and 2mm long (this is a highly cropped macro shot).

[image]

Google reverse image search turns up only "Springtail", and all the matching images show a bug with the same general shape, but larger and having long tails.

Question: What is this bug, and could it be causing the problem with the cedar?